# want xpath result by casperjs

Tags: xpath, casperjs

I just try to echo all HTML of google result to standout. but I got the ten time 'undefined' only.
undefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefined

below is my code, what is wrong?

```
casper.then(
function(){
    this.echo(
    this.evaluate(function(){
        var returnHTML="";
        var elementsResult=__utils__.getElementsByXPath("id('ires')/ol/li");

        for (ele in elementsResult){
            returnHTML=returnHTML + ele.outerHTML;
        }

        return returnHTML;
    }));
}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do? You could get the HTML of the results simply with `return document.getElementById('ires').innerHTML;`.